# Notifying Activity From ViewModel

Tags: android, mvvm, android-mvvm

I am new to MVVM android, I want to make a simple Login form with 2 input fields of email and password, 1 button of Login and 1 progressbar. I am using viewmodel to catch values of email/password from XML using binding and onclick binding as well to call viewmodel's onclick function. So basically viewmodel is now listening to everything in XML.

My question is, I want to show a progressbar during the login and thus want to notify activity class from viewmodel that "hey, user just clicked on that Login button, show the progressbar we have login process going on" or "hey, now navigate to dashboard since the login is completed" or "hey, we have an error, show an error alertdialog".

I can use an interface to wrap activity and pass it to viewmodel and then call its methods but I do not want to use that approach as it is not MVVM I believe. Should I create a Status variable in viewmodel and then observe it from activity?

So what's the solution here?

Answer (score 1):

You can do using Live data in your view model. checkout sample code for that.

```
var btnClicked:MutableLiveData<Boolean> = MutableLivedata<Boolean>()
```

In your click function use this

```
fun onClick(){
  btnClicked.value = true
}
```

Then use this code in activity to show the progress bar.

```
viewModel.btnClicked.observe(this, Observer {
        showProgressbar();//You funtion to show the progress bar
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using LiveData. Make a live data variable whose value will be updated by viewmodel methods with login status and the activity class will observe this live data variable for status updates.